# Type is not defined VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET project where I create a class that inherits a ComboBox:

```
Public Class myComboBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
End Class
```

In the project where I am using this, if I add this control, myComboBox onto a form, I get the following error:

> Error  1   Type 'myProject.myComboBox' is not defined.

If I do the exact same thing in a brand new project, everything works just fine.  The project has no errors and will execute.

Any ideas?

Comment: Visual Studio Window > Build > Clean Solution > Re-Build solution , lemme know if it worked for you :)

Comment: Be sure to put your types inside a Namespace so you don't have to guess at their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first try would be `Clean` the solution,and `Rebuild` it.

`Visual Studio` > `Build` > `Clean Solution` and then `Re-Build Solution`

Your best bet is to check both your custom-control and project's targeted Dot.Net framework is the same.If they are different,then this is an obvious error

But as you mentioned , it works in a new project right ? So , create a new project,add all the .vb files from your previous project,double click to load the designer(there might be one or two errors but they are easily fixable).Then you have a completely new project,Now add the .dll of the usercontrol/Custom Control you created.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The clean/rebuild did not work for me.  The class was created inside the solution so I don't think it could be the targeted Dot.Net framework, right?

Comment: I am not including a .dll.  I am adding a Class to the project, and editing the Class as shown in my question.  Maybe that's not a valid thing to do?  I can certainly follow the same steps and recreate the solution though...

Comment: Create the class in a new class library project , get the dll then , then follow my steps to create the new project .. Hope it works

Comment: I followed what you said and for the most part was able to save a decent portion of my work.  I had about 40 instances of this custom control on a form and when I reopened the project (originally) the form would not display because of the errors in the designer file.  I renamed the control to the new dll's namespace and then was able to successfully build however I got an immediate error upon running the GUI.  I bit the bullet and just manually replaced all of the controls and now the project will execute.  Not sure what I missed in the designer but good enough for me.  THANKS!!!